# How to delete the first name and last name columns in django user model?

Tags: django, django-models

I created a custom user model just like the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project) said, when I ran the `makemigrations` I went to the folder of migrations and deleted the first name and last name columns inside the `0001_initial.py` and then I ran the `migrate` command, but when I ran the `createsuperuser` command it throwed an error in the terminal that `django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: myapp_usermodel.first_name`

How can I fix this?
I want to delete the first name and last name columns because I'm not using them

**EDIT:** this is the user model

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

# Create your models here.
class usermodel(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=60)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

Comment: You make a custom user model. How exactly did you make this model?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I went to the folder of migrations and deleted the first name and last name columns inside the `0001_initial.py`

You shouldn't do that. This will indeed prevent Django from *creating* the columns. But now it will each time query under the impression that the columns are there. Furthermore if you make migrations again, it will try to add extra columns.

You should simply use the *method resolution order (MRO)* and set the field to `None`:

```
class usermodel(AbstractUser):
    first_name = None
    last_name = None
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

You probably also better remove the table in the database and the migration file and make migrations again, and migrate the database.