# How to remove specific fields from the django User Model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-authentication, django-users

From the Django User Model, I'd like to remove some fields such as `'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'date_joined'`.
I want no changes in the Auth system of the User Model, i.e. I still want authentication to be done using the username. I just want to remove some unrequired fields.

Will I need to extend the `AbstractBaseUser` model for this, or can this be achieved just by extending the `AbstractUser` model?

Or is there any other way also to do this ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: This will maybe already answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64391320/how-to-delete-the-first-name-and-last-name-columns-in-django-user-model